# edge caching secure content on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, browser-cache, offline-caching

In my app, I have to serve huge secure files ( svg drawings etc ) that I want to show only to logged in user. File do not change much, and if it does, It do have different url, so I would like to use edge cache on google app engine for faster loading to already logged in user.

My question is, how do I make it secure ? i.e. if the user logged out and if someone else use his browser can he see that content ? if so, how do I prevent it ?

Related: How do I prevent browser from remembering a url of a content on my website.

Answer (score 3):

One of the solutions could be using [Google Cloud Storage with ACL](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#scopes), i.e. in the way that only a particular logged in user has access to that file. This solution is limited to Google Accounts though.

UPDATE: Google Cloud Storage now has a [short-life signed URLs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs):

"...you could provide a signed URL to a user which would allow the user to access that resource for a limited time. Anyone who knows the URL can access the resource for a limited time. (You specify the expiration time in the query string to be signed.)"
- so, that could be even closer to what you need.

Another solution is that you serve your huge file from your dynamic handlers. This however will consume a lot of CPU and bandwidth. Also, you'll still be limited by [GAE quotas](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Resources).

Related: you can't prevent browser from remembering visited URLs or any other kind of history. It depends solely on the specific browser and user preferences (not accessible to your app / javascript/whatever). The only thing you can ask your users is to clear their history, cookie and whatnot when they log out.

Answer (score 1):

You could set expiration in the appconfig

Sorry I just have a german link (just try, maybe google switches to your language)
http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html

As long as not expired the browser could cache the file locally. This results in a small load time. However, if the cache is too small, the browser will request the file again.

A good browser will only make secured file to the logged user available.
However, you have no guarantee which browser is in use. Your user could always download secure file and publish them anywhere.

When a user give the login to third users, they could all the time access the secured files.

I don't think you could avoid to remember any links. In some way it is a contradiction to the above.